# val behavior in scala REPL and Intellij

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop, scala-repl

as expected reassignment is giving error like below in REPL

```
scala> val a=1
a: Int = 1

scala> a=2
<console>:12: error: reassignment to val
       a=2
        ^
```

But the below reassignment is not giving error in REPL when `a=2` preceded with val.

```
scala> val a=1
a: Int = 1

scala> val a=2
a: Int = 2
```

When  I execute the below code in Intellij its giving error.

```
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val x = 1
    val x = 2
  }
}
```

Why `val a=1` and `val a=2` are not giving any error in REPL(error if it is only a=2) but error in Intellij.

Comment: The **REPL** allows you to shadows old definitions with new values, this is useful for experimenting but could lead to obscure code, that is why this only works on a **REPL**.  - BTW, note that you can emulate that behaviour in code too like this `{ val x = 1 { val x = 2 } }` note the inner block, each block can shadow previously defined variables, but once you exit the block the old variable exists again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Scala docs REPL overview](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/repl/overview.html#power-mode):

> - every line of input is compiled separately.
> - dependencies on previous lines are included by automatically generated imports.

Combining these two facts, we can understand that they are not in the same namespace, unlike the example you provided which 2 variables called `x` are in the same class.

Answer (score 2):

The REPL is intended for rapid friction-less experimentation. It would be *very* annoying if you had to restart from scratch just because you accidentally mistyped `val a = 32` when you meant `val a = 23`.

Therefore, the REPL is designed in such a way that it gives the *appearance* of breaking the rules of Scala, although it actually doesn't. The code that gets *actually compiled* corresponding to the code you *entered* looks a little bit like this:

```scala
object line$1 {
  val a=1
}

object line$2 {
  import line$1._
  val a=2
}
```