# Why Scala in REPL (or worksheet) and Scala in IDE don't work the same?

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

I'm a beginner learning Scala. I was referring to the [Scala documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/two-types-variables.html).

The documentation says:

> The REPL isn’t 100% the same as working with source code in an IDE, so
> there are a few things you can do in the REPL that you can’t do when
> working on real-world code in a project. One example of this is that
> you can redefine a `val` field in the REPL, like this:

```
scala> val age = 18
age: Int = 18

scala> val age = 19
age: Int = 19
```

> `val` fields can’t be redefined like that in the real world, but they
> can be redefined in the REPL playground.

They have mentioned that it works differently, but what is the need for that?

Also, I have noticed that Scala is weakly-typed when I use it as Worksheet on [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/) but, strongly-typed when I turn off the worksheet mode.
Why does a language behave differently in two different modes?

Edit: There was confusion. Scala works the same in no-worksheet mode.

Comment: _"but what is the need for that?"_ because usually a **REPL** is a place to play with the code, so assuming you are debugging an algorithm it would be way tedious if you can not replace a `val` with a new value. - _" I have noticed that Scala is weakly-typed when I use it as Worksheet on Scastie but, strongly-typed when I turn off the worksheet mode"_ **Scala** is always strongly-typed. However, you may be confused due to type-inference or due to the iterative nature of a worksheet, if you could show an example it may be easer to explain what happened and why it looked like it was weealy-typed

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I tried this in worksheet mode:

`var temp = "hello"`
`temp = temp + 10`
`print(temp)`

Output was: `hello10`

Comment: That is not weakly-typed perse, that is the infamous `any2str` **implicit conversion** that the language has by default in the `Predef`. That is just a consequence of the **Java** origins of the language. This also works in a normal / compiled _(no-worksheet)_ mode... just try not to use it, for building strings it is better to use the simple **String interpolator**.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64667712/2359227