# Scala 3: Unexpected Successful Compilation when Using Variable Before Assignment

Tags: scala, scope, variable-assignment, scala-3

I was expecting this to raise an error as I'm trying to use `x` before assigning it. Here's the Scala 3.3.1 REPL:

```
scala> val x: Int =
     |  val y: Int = x + 10
     |  y
     |
val x: Int = 10
```

Why is the result 10? When Scala evaluates the `x + 10`, it assumes `x=0`?

Comment: Strange. I'm following your post to look at any answer, because, for me, Scala is one of the most difficult language to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's happening because of the same REPL-trickery that allows you to compile and execute

```
> val x = 1
> val x = 2
```

in the interactive REPL-mode: the `val`s are not compiled as local variables inside of function bodies, but as members of wrapper objects, as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64676014/2707792).

In your particular case, when you type your example

```
scala> val x: Int =
     |  val y: Int = x + 10
     |  y
     |
```

into the REPL, it gets wrapped into a synthetic "[execution template](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/repl/overview.html)"-object, which behaves roughly as the following script:

```
object replInputLine$1 {
  val x: Int =
    val y = x + 10
    y
  println(x)
}

@main def entry(): Unit =
  replInputLine$1
```

What is happening in this script? Well, the `replInputLine$1`-object is initialized. As always during object-initialization, the member `x: Int` is allocated and initialized to `0` during the allocation of the object, and then the actual object initializer is executed, which updates `x` to `10`.

Since `x` is an object member, and not a local variable in a method body, it can be accessed without problems.

If instead you tried to use the same code snippet inside of a method body, you would get compilation errors, as the following example shows:

```
@main def entry(): Unit =
  val x: Int =
    val y: Int = x + 10
    y
  println(x)
```

This will fail the compilation with the message

> Reference error: [...] x is a forward reference extending over the definition of x

So, it's just an artifact resulting from the fact that REPL treats `val`s as members of a synthetic object instead of treating them as local variables.

Playing "language-lawyer" games with the REPL is pointless and boring: if you want to understand what the compiler is doing "for real", don't test it in the REPL, write a separate program, then compile it.